# Rails: Devise Login as another user issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my application, users have the ability to invite others to be 'Contributors' on their account. These contributors once they have logged in, are redirected to a dashboard that shows each account they can log in as.

The below is a controller that is used to allow Contributors and School Admins to log into Athlete accounts. When the original user logs into an account the app checks for the `session[:original_user_id]` variable to display a message banner across the top of the screen with a link so that the admin can log back into their account - This is what I am having issues with trying to figure out how to log the original user back in.

SignInAsController:

```
class SignInAsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  include SchoolAdmin::Athletes

  def create
    session[:original_user_id] = if (current_user.school_admin? || current_user.athlete_contributor?)
      current_user.id
    else
      nil
    end

    user = User.find(params[:id])

    if current_user.can_manage?(user)
      sign_out(User.find(current_user.id))
      handle_request(athlete)
      redirect_to user_root_path
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You do not have access to that account"
    end
  end

  private

    def handle_request(athlete)
      sign_in(:user, athlete, { bypass: true })
    end
end
```

UserModel can_manage? method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #other methods

  def can_manage?(user)
    if athlete_contributor?
      managed_athletes.include?(user)
    elsif school_admin?
      active_subscription.athletes.include?(user)
    end

    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. It allows an Admin user to login as another User.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def become
    return unless current_user.is_an_admin?
    sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

You can also do `sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]), { :bypass => true })` if you don't want to update `last_sign_in_at` and `current_sign_in` when admin becomes the user.

Answer (score 0):

Devise has `sessions` & `registrations` controllers, which allow you to create & override various methods for devise

---

**Sessions**

Considering the logging-in process is about `creating` a session, I'd look at implementing my own method to `destroy` the current session & `create` a new one with the admin stats, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
devise_scope :user do
    post "admin", :to => "devise/sessions#admin_switch"
end

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

     #Switch to "admin" mode
     def admin_switch
          sign_out #method to destroy current user's session
          sign_in #create new session -- needs more work
     end

end
```

This is meant to demonstrate how you'd achieve your goal. If you want me to add some more code, I certainly will amend my post! Specifically, the `sign_in` command won't work (needs specific data passed to it, and uses Warden)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch User](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) gem which can work with:
:devise, :authlogic, :clearance, :restful_authentication or :sorcery

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/controllers/users/impersonations_controller.rb

this functionality “impersonating another user”. an admin can go onto Admin::Users#index -> Find a user, and impersonate them.  That is, sign into their account.need a button that posts to this action

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb#L11

```
def impersonate
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :impersonate, @user
    # Impersonate
    session[:impersonation_user_id] = current_user.id
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    warden.session_serializer.store(@user, Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(@user))
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
```

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_authorization_check only: [:destroy]
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:impersonation_user_id])
    # Reset impersonation
    session[:impersonation_user_id] = nil
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    warden.session_serializer.store(@user, Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(@user))
    redirect_to(admin_users_path)
  end
end
```

Which uses devise, to set the session[:impersonation_user_id] so later you know you are impersonating another use, and then this warden.session_serializer.store which signs you in as a new user.
If you close the tab. Reopen the tab. You will still be impersonating that user.
Put a partial in the site (haml) to display an alert to the user on every page when they’re impersonating

```
  .bg-warning.d-print-none.text-center
    You are logged in as <strong>#{current_user}</strong>.
    = link_to 'click here', impersonate_path, 'data-method': :delete
    to return to your original account.
```

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/views/layouts/_impersonate.html.haml